# Mega Menu and divs with equal height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been working on a mega menu which so is fully functional except one design issue.

I need to grow submenu wrapper div with the text which is place inside another wrapper.

At present my sub menu text appear out the container.

[jsFiddle Eaxmple](http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/3/) and [jsfiddle Full window view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5eecT/3/show/#)

Outer `div class=dropdown` nested `div class=dd-panel`

In fiddle example `Menu One >  Sub Menu Two`  text shows up outside div with class `dropdown` wrapper. I want it to grow outer div to grow with the nested elements.

I tried changes properties but nothing working i might be doing something wrong somewhere.

Do we need to do it with jquery or it is possible with css.

Comment: Could you put together an MS Paint or link to a depiction of what you want this to look like when behaving correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), `position: absolute` elements are removed from the normal flow for computing width and height of other elements (siblings, parents).

Your problem is that your `.dd-panel` elements are placed with this attribute, and will not count against their `.dropdown` parent's height.

I don't see a pure css solution to this. I would add code to the

```
$(".dropdown ul li").mouseenter()
```

callback to compute the height of the `ul`, the height of the displayed `.dd-panel`, and set the `.dropdown`'s height to the max of these two.

[**edit**] For some reason I haven't identified, `.dd-panel` elements will not return their true height when using `$().height()`. With your fiddle, you can get the "correct" height from your `.media-caption` nodes.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/10/)

---

A remark on your code : instead of

```
$(".dropdown ul li").each(function()
     $(this).mouseenter(function(){ ...
```

you can simply write :

```
$(".dropdown ul li").mouseenter(function(){ ...
```

or use event delegation :

```
$(".dopdown").on("mouseenter", "ul li", function(){ ...
```

Comment: i tried    `$(".dropdown ul li").hover(function () {            var aaaaa = $(".dd-panel span").height();             alert(aaaaa);            //$(this).css("height", aaaaa);            $(this)(".dd-panel").css({ "height": aaaaa })        });` but it is not working could you please show it on fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate your help. It is working for on your fiddle i will implement it and see if it works on actual code..

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://www.fiddle.net/5eecT/11/) i have added padding-bottom to your .dd-panel class